# How to add global event listener

Tags: react-native, expo, func

I`m trying to add a global listener instead of add and remove for each screen.

So I'm trying to add a wrapper to the app and add the event listener code in the wrapper but the loaded screen is totally empty. Any ideas on how to fix that code or implement the goal in another way?

App.js:

```
const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);

export default () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <AlbumProvider>
        <GlobalProvider>
          <AppWrapper>
            <App
              ref={(navigator) => {
                setNavigator(navigator);
              }}
            />
          </AppWrapper>
        </GlobalProvider>
      </AlbumProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```

Wrapper:

```
const AppWrapper = ({ navigation, children }) => {
  const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);
  const [appStateVisible, setAppStateVisible] = useState(appState.current);

  useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener("change", _handleAppStateChange);
    };
  }, []);

  _storeData = async () => {
    console.log("_storeData method");
  };

  const _handleAppStateChange = async (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === "active"
    ) {
      console.log("App has come to the foreground!");
    } else if (appState.current == "active") {
      _storeData();
    }

    appState.current = nextAppState;
    setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
  };

  return <>
  </>;
};

export default AppWrapper;
```